# Flask Babel working locally but not on GAE

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, multilingual, flask-babel

I have been using Flask Babel to run a multilingual app for couples of month now.
It was working fine until late September.
It is working fine locally but when pushed to the GAE, the translation is not working.
GAE is storing every version pushed and I was able to went back to version where the translation was working, made sure the configuration was exactly the same but it's still not working.

I made sure the messages.po is pushed and use the tag --verbose=info to make sure it's pushed and indeed I can see the sourceUrl and the sha1Sum of the file in the cloud storage.

I checked that the path translations/en/LC_MESSAGES match the local on babel 'en'

Comment: You need to be specific - what do you mean by not working, what language is your code in, did you make any changes to the code (if so, what is it)?

Comment: The language of the website is French and I'm trying to also have an english version. When I say it's not working I mean that the translations is not operating, the HTML text are not switching to english when I hit the button translate. 
The language code is updated from 'fr' to 'en' but that's it, the routes and the text are not updated